# Bastion sound is static on Linux

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, bastion

When I start Bastion directly everything works fine, but when I launch the game through Steam, the sound comes out as static.

Oddly enough when I switch to a VT  with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>, and then switch back to my desktop, it seems to fix the sound.

I am using Arch Linux, Pulseaudio, GDM, and Cinnamon.

Does anyone have an idea why the sound is static every time I launch through Steam?

Comment: What's the real question here? It seems the issue resolved itself based on your info.

Comment: It hasn't resolved itself. Every single time the game is launched the sound is messed up. Switching to a VT does get the sound working but that is hardly a fix..

Comment: does sound work on other steam games? Try re-installing (if you won't be upset if you lose data)  or try restarting your computer

Comment: Yes, it works on other games. My sound is just fine, it even works when launching Basion outside of steam.

Comment: then... Why don't you just play without using steam?

Comment: Because outside of steam I don't get to complete the achievements and I'm trying to 100% the game.